# Dropdown dependent values to be fetch from multiple models using ajax

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I searched all the documentation over `Yii` but not got the answer of it.So I came here finally.
I have the following schema

```
Table Schools
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id               | int(10)      | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| school_name      | varchar(100) | NO   |     |                     |                |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+

Table Students

+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id               | int(10)      | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| school_id        | int(10)      | NO   | FK  |                     |                |
| student_name     | varchar(100) | NO   |     |                     |                |
| roll_no          | varchar(80)  | NO   |     |                     |                |
| class            | varchar(20)  | NO   |     |    |                |                |
| subjects         | varchar(100) | NO   |     |                     |                |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

I have made `models and CRUD` for the both models.In models my relation is like this

In `Students.php` the relation is like

```
  public function relations()
  {
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
      'School' => array(self::BELONGS_TO,'Schools','school_id'),
    );
  }
```

In `Schools.php` the relation is like

```
public function relations()
  {
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
      'student' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Students', 'school_id'),
    );
  }
```

Now I made the `two models rendered in a single page` so that I can enter all the respective fields in a single form.

```
 In the _form.php file of Students I have made some change in student_name like this
         <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'student_name'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->dropdownList($model,'student_name', CHtml::listData(Students::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'student_name'), array('empty'=>array('Select'=>'--Select One---'))); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'student_name'); ?>
```

Now for this piece of code I got `all the student name from the Student model`.
 So my problem is when I am getting the student name from the `dropdown list` and going to select a student it will also fetch all the respective values of the student to be rendered in the `_form.php` without click on save button.So that user don't have to put it again manually.
 I think `ajax and json encode` will work here but don't know how to make them work here.

**[Update]**

Here is `StudentsController` code

```
 public function actionDisCoor() {
    $model = School::model()->findByPk($_POST['Students']['student_id']);
    $data=CHtml::listData($data,'id','name');
    foreach($data as $value=>$name)
    {
      echo CHtml::tag('option',array('value'=>$value),CHtml::encode($name),true);
    }
  }
```

Here is `_form.php` code for `Students`

```
  <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'student_name'); ?>
    <?php  $List = CHtml::listData(Students::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'student_name');
?>
    <?php echo $form->dropdownList($model,'student_name',$List,
                                array('onChange'=>CHtml::ajax(array(
                                'url' => CController::createUrl('DisCoor'),
                                'type' => 'POST',                     
                               'update'=>'#school_id',
                                )),'style'=>'width:180px;'
                                    )
                                )?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'student_name'); ?>
  </div>
```

Here is the code for `accessRules()`

```
  public function accessRules()
  {
    return array(
      array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
        'actions'=>array('index','view'),
        'users'=>array('*'),
      ),
      array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
        'actions'=>array('create','update'),
        'users'=>array('@'),
      ),
      array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
        'actions'=>array('create','update','DisCoor'),
        'users'=>array('@'),
      ),
      array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
        'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
        'users'=>array('admin'),
      ),
      array('deny',  // deny all users
        'users'=>array('*'),
      ),
    );
  }
```

After all that when I saw in firebug I got the error.Here is the screen shot
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Its easy. Please read [Creating a dependent dropdown](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/24/) . Hopefully it would answer all your queries.

you can also do something like
in following example it is critical to see that i have called `onChange` and it makes form submit

```
     <?php echo
 $List = CHtml::listData(Students::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'student_name');
 $form->dropdownList($model,'student_name',$List,
                                array('onChange'=>
                                CHtml::ajax(array(
                                'url' => CController::createUrl('DisCoor'),
                                'type' => 'POST',                     
                               'update'=>'#school_id',
                                )),'style'=>'width:180px;'        
                                    )
                                )?>
```

and in my controller i did something like

```
$model = School::model()->findByPk($_POST['Jobs']['student_id']);
                 $data=CHtml::listData($data,'id','name');
foreach($data as $value=>$name)
{
    echo CHtml::tag('option',
               array('value'=>$value),CHtml::encode($name),true);
}
```

now #school_id is the dropDown that needs to be updated.

I have given you almost everything that you need
Best of Luck

Comment: thank you for your quick response.I have ssen that wiki.That one is for two drop-down dependent on each other.But I want the value of that certain record to be fetched which is made selected in dropdown list in _form.php page.

Comment: can you edit your answer with both my models name as required by there.sorry to say you I am little bit confused here.

Comment: another thing the code that you have mentioned in Controller should it be `actionCreate` or I have to again create a function for that.

Comment: you have to create another action that would respond to `AJAX` calls. I have done most with present knowledge. Now it is upto you to try and post your effort. We all are busy but we want to help so you have to do your part on your own. Ask questions if something is unclear

Comment: I used your code with the _form.php file and in controller I used `actionDisCoor()` to use the codes that to be used in controller.When I made select the option[student name]it showed an error which can be seen through console of firefox.The error was like `"NetworkError: 500 PHP Error - http://localhost/SchoolApps/index.php?r=students/DisCoor"`.The error is for there is no such file has been created in that link I think.So how to solve this one?

Comment: you can hit F12 on chrome(i use it) and then goto network tab to see the AJAX requests. You need to see what your `$_POST` has. I used `$_POST['Jobs']['student_id']` here you need to figure what is coming in place of `Jobs` hopefully it would be your `model` name. Please update your question with your controller and view code

Comment: I have edited the question with controller code and view code.I have also attached the screen shot of ajax request.

Comment: have you placed action name in `accessRules`

Comment: yes I have.See the edited question once again.I have made it updated.